# How to fetch array of array data in angular 2?

Tags: arrays, angular

How to fetch array of array data in angular 2.

My json data is as follows,

```
[[{
  "pk_emp_id":5,
  "tenant_id":"Zone1",
  "location_id":1,
  "emp_number":"sk44",
  "prefix":"",
  "first_name":"qqqqq",
  "middle_name":"www",
  "last_name":"eeee",
  "display_name":"qqqq",
  "full_name":"qqq qqqq",
  "email":"qqqq@gmail.com",
  "gender":"Female",
  "emp_type_id":2,
  "date_of_hire":191000,
  "date_of_birth":null,
  "manager_id":7,
  "phone_number":"9877654",
  "position":"SE",
  "responsibility":"",
  "notes":"",
  "contracted":"0",
  "street":"vidyanagar",
  "state":"Karnataka",
  "city":"hubli",
  "zip_code":"9898",
  "dob":-19800000,
  "ssn":"",
  "deleted":0
},{
  "pk_empt_id":2,
  "empt_tenant_id":"2",
  "***empt_name***":"temporary",
  "deleted":0
}]]
```

How can I fetch `empt_name` in datatable(row data)?

Answer (score 1):

```
    let dummyArr = [
      [{
        "pk_emp_id": 5,
        "tenant_id": "Zone1",
        "location_id": 1,
        "emp_number": "sk44",
        "prefix": "",
        "first_name": "qqqqq",
        "middle_name": "www",
        "last_name": "eeee",
        "display_name": "qqqq",
        "full_name": "qqq qqqq",
        "email": "qqqq@gmail.com",
        "gender": "Female",
        "emp_type_id": 2,
        "date_of_hire": 191000,
        "date_of_birth": null,
        "manager_id": 7,
        "phone_number": "9877654",
        "position": "SE",
        "responsibility": "",
        "notes": "",
        "contracted": "0",
        "street": "vidyanagar",
        "state": "Karnataka",
        "city": "hubli",
        "zip_code": "9898",
        "dob": -19800000,
        "ssn": "",
        "deleted": 0
      }, {
        "pk_empt_id": 2,
        "empt_tenant_id": "2",
        "***empt_name***": "temporary",
        "deleted": 0
      }]
    ];

    dummyArr.forEach(element =>{
        element.forEach(element2=>{
            console.log(element2)
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I believe you have exposed a GET method in your web api
2. In Angular using HTTP service

> this.http.get("").subscribe(result => {
>   conosle.log(result[1].empt_name) });

Answer (score 0):

You  can take it in an array and read  it like this:

```js
x = [
  [{
    "pk_emp_id": 5,
    "tenant_id": "Zone1",
    "location_id": 1,
    "emp_number": "sk44",
    "prefix": "",
    "first_name": "qqqqq",
    "middle_name": "www",
    "last_name": "eeee",
    "display_name": "qqqq",
    "full_name": "qqq qqqq",
    "email": "qqqq@gmail.com",
    "gender": "Female",
    "emp_type_id": 2,
    "date_of_hire": 191000,
    "date_of_birth": null,
    "manager_id": 7,
    "phone_number": "9877654",
    "position": "SE",
    "responsibility": "",
    "notes": "",
    "contracted": "0",
    "street": "vidyanagar",
    "state": "Karnataka",
    "city": "hubli",
    "zip_code": "9898",
    "dob": -19800000,
    "ssn": "",
    "deleted": 0
  }, {
    "pk_empt_id": 2,
    "empt_tenant_id": "2",
    "***empt_name***": "temporary",
    "deleted": 0
  }]
]
$('#a').text(x[0][1]['***empt_name***'])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='a'>sadsad </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just Javascript object manipulation.
You can do something like :

```
outerArray.forEach(innerArray =>{
  if(innerArray.length){
     innerArray.forEach(element =>{
        //do somthing here with element.empt_name 
        console.log(element.empt_name);
    });
  }
})
```